# How to access controls in listview's layouttemplate?

Tags: asp.net, listview

How do I set a property of a user control in `ListView`'s `LayoutTemplate` from the code-behind?

```
<asp:ListView ...>
<LayoutTemplate>
<myprefix:MyControl id="myControl" ... />
</LayoutTemplate>
...
</asp:ListView>
```

I want to do this:

```
myControl.SomeProperty = somevalue;
```

Please notice that my control is not in `ItemTemplate`, it is in `LayoutTemplate`, so it does not exist for all items, it exists only once. So I should be able to access it once, not for every data bound item.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To set a property of a control that is inside the LayoutTemplate, simply use the FindControl method on the ListView control.

```
var control = (MyControl)myListView.FindControl("myControlId");
```

Answer (score 18):

```
var control = (MyControl)myListView.FindControl("myControlId");
```

This will work but make sure you do it after the data bind or the LayoutTemplate will not have been created thus throwing an error.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol.aspx) method on each ListViewItem.

```
var control = (MyControl)Item.FindControl("yourControlId");
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered in this Stack Overflow question:
[[Access a control inside a the LayoutTemplate of a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433846/access-a-control-inside-a-the-layouttemplate-of-a-listview)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433846/access-a-control-inside-a-the-layouttemplate-of-a-listview)

See the comment on the accepted answer by tanathos.

I know this was asked over a year ago, but it's one of the first results for the search term I used to get here, so I wanted to leave the answer for anyone else who stumbled upon it.

Answer (score 0):

The layout gets created, and fires a LayoutCreated event that says the layout has been created in the system.

Then, you can use listview.FindControl to get a reference to that control.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need the VB.net version, here it is:

```
Dim control = CType(myListView.FindControl("myControlId"), MyControl)
```