# Access a control inside a the LayoutTemplate of a ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, asp.net-3.5

How do I access a Control in the `LayoutTemplate` of a `ListView` control?

I need to get to `litControlTitle` and set its `Text` attribute.

```
<asp:ListView ID="lv" runat="server">
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <asp:Literal ID="litControlTitle" runat="server" />
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Any thoughts?  Perhaps via the `OnLayoutCreated` event?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try this:

```
((Literal)lv.FindControl("litControlTitle")).Text = "Your text";
```

Comment: I tried that initially, but that didn't work.  Then I came here.  Thanks though!

Comment: very strange... I place this code inside the callback of OnLayoutCreated, and when I bind the ListView it works fine...

Comment: oh, well I didn't put it in that event, trying now

Comment: For anyone reading this answer, make sure you call `FindControl` after the `ListView` has been bound to a source (i.e., after calling `DataBind` on you ListView). Otherwise the ListView's Layout Template will not be ready by the time you look up the control, hence `FindControl` will not succeed.

Comment: Also: if data binding occurs on an empty collection then the control cannot be found. Do a null reference check for this situation.

Answer (score 17):

The complete solution:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lv" OnLayoutCreated="OnLayoutCreated" runat="server">
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <asp:Literal ID="lt_Title" runat="server" />
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

In codebehind:

```
protected void OnLayoutCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (lv.FindControl("lt_Title") as Literal).Text = "Your text";
}
```

Comment: This solution is more stable than tanathos's. tanathos's sometimes doesn't work when DataBind and access in the same method.

Answer (score 4):

This technique works for template layout; use the init event of the control:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lv" runat="server" OnDataBound="lv_DataBound">
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <asp:Literal ID="litControlTitle" runat="server" OnInit="litControlTitle_Init" />
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

And capture a reference to the control for use in the code-behind (e.g) in the ListView's DataBound event:

```
private Literal litControlTitle;

protected void litControlTitle_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    litControlTitle = (Literal) sender;
}

protected void lv_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    litControlTitle.Text = "Title...";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Nested LV Loop:

```
void lvSecondLevel_LayoutCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Literal litText = lvFirstLevel.FindControl("lvSecondLevel").FindControl("litText") as Literal;
    litMainMenuText.Text = "This is test";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need the VB version, here it is

```
Dim litControl = CType(lv.FindControl("litControlTitle"), Literal)
litControl.Text = "your text"
```