# accessing label control from listview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I unable to access label from listview.
I have been reading all posts, but nothing seems to work.
Here is my code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ListView1.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    Label someLabel = (Label) ListView1.Items[i].FindControl("nItemsId");
                    if (someLabel != null)
                        someLabel.Text = "100";
                }


 <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1" DataKeyNames="ProductId" DataSourceID="GameTable" OnItemCommand="On_Select_Item" >
      <LayoutTemplate>
           <table runat="server" id="gametable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0">
              <tr style="height: 20px; font-size: 20px; color: Red">
             <th>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="5" ID="nItemsId" cssClass="cart">        
                 </asp:Label>
              </th>
              </tr>

......................................
------------------------------
</asp.ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label control inside the LayoutTemplate so it's not part of any `ListView` item. Try just:

```
ListView.FindControl("nItemsId")
```

What you have would work if the label was part of `ItemTemplate`

More on this topic here: [Access a control inside a the LayoutTemplate of a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433846/access-a-control-inside-a-the-layouttemplate-of-a-listview)