# unable to access table back color property

Tags: c#, asp.net

For some reason in the C# code behind for asp.net, i cannot call the table by it's ID to set it's back color property. I tried  and  and nothing seems to work

Here is my asp.net table tag:

```
<table id="ptbl" runat="server" cellpadding="2" width="640px" border="1">
```

here is something similar to what i what to do in the C# code behind but it does not recognize the id

```
ptbl.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:red")");
```

Any ideas/suggestions?

Update: here is the code. There is a layout template in it so somehow it can't see the table id, but if I take that out of it then it sees it. What can i do. I need the listview to get the data

```
  <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" Style="color: white; font-weight: bold">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="ptbl" runat="server" cellpadding="2" width="640px" border="1" style="color: black; font-weight: bold">
                <tr runat="server">
                    <th runat="server">Ps</th>
                    <th runat="server">P</th>
                    <th runat="server">T</th>
                </tr>
                <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
            </table>
            <asp:DataPager runat="server" ID="ContactsDataPager" PageSize="90">
                <Fields>
                    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ShowFirstPageButton="true" ShowLastPageButton="true"
                        FirstPageText="|&lt;&lt; " LastPageText=" &gt;&gt;|"
                        NextPageText=" &gt; " PreviousPageText=" &lt; " />
                </Fields>
            </asp:DataPager>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr runat="server">
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"><%# Eval("Ps") %></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"><%# Eval("P") %></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"><%# Eval("T") %></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Again the layout template is causing the issue. how can i use the listview and the table with the layout template. I know this has morphed a bit now , but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is ptb1 not recognizable in codebehind?

Comment: @AkashKC - correct ptbl (L not a 1) is not being recognized in the code behind

Comment: It's recognized in my codebehind. but you have compiler error in adding attribute. it should be like `ptbl.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:red");`

Comment: ok, i see what happened but it does not solve my problem if i add an id to the layouttemplate below. see edit above:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access controls in listview's layouttemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48616/how-to-access-controls-in-listviews-layouttemplate)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the ptbl table until DataBind() has been called on ListView1. After it has been called *and* there is data in the dataset, then you can reference the the ptbl table like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var tbl = new DataTable();
        tbl.Columns.Add("Ps", typeof(Int32));
        tbl.Columns.Add("P", typeof(string));
        tbl.Columns.Add("T", typeof(string));

        var r = tbl.NewRow();
        r[0] = 99;
        r[1] = "Hey";
        r[2] = "USA";
        tbl.Rows.Add(r);
        ListView1.DataSource = tbl;
        ListView1.DataBind();

        var ptbl = (HtmlTable)ListView1.FindControl("ptbl");
        ptbl.Style.Add("background-color", "red");
    }
```